# Powershell WQL query (SCCM) how do you filter on two WHERE?

Tags: sql, powershell

Being really new to WQL queries from SCCM via Powershell, I have managed this so far :

```
[string]$poste_entre = Read-Host "Poste"
[string]$poste_entre = $poste_entre.Insert(0,"%")
[string]$poste_entre += "%"
""


[string[]]$postes=(Get-WmiObject -ComputerName SSigcimpr001 -Namespace "root\sms\site_pr1" -Query ("select SMS_R_System.Name from  SMS_R_System WHERE SMS_R_System.Name like '" + $poste_entre + "' ")).Name


$postes
```

I enter a partial name (0293) in this case, and adding % at the beginning and end of the string (wildcard), the query returns the two computers i'm searching correctly :

```
Poste: 0293

A0293
P0293
```

However, the computer "A0293" is an INACTIVE computer, I would like for the query NOT to return it so it only returns ACTIVE computers.

I thought I could do the query like this:

```
[string[]]$postes=(Get-WmiObject -ComputerName SSigcimpr001 -Namespace "root\sms\site_pr1" -Query ("select SMS_R_System.Name from  SMS_R_System WHERE SMS_R_System.Name like '" + $poste_entre + "' AND SMS_R_System.Active = '1' ")).Name
```

but it's not working, it still returns both computers, but one is clearly inactive? Why isn't the query returning only the active computer?

Thank you so much! 
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up finding the answer with the help of langstrom, final query is this :

```
[string[]]$postes=(Get-WmiObject -ComputerName SSigcimpr001 -Namespace "root\sms\site_pr1" -Query ("select SMS_R_System.Name from  SMS_R_System  inner join SMS_G_System_CH_ClientSummary on SMS_G_System_CH_ClientSummary.ResourceId = SMS_R_System.ResourceId where SMS_G_System_CH_ClientSummary.ClientActiveStatus = 1 AND SMS_R_System.Name like '" + $poste_entre + "' ")).Name
```

Answer (score 1):

The possible values for `SMS_R_System.Active` are either `0` or `1`.

`[string[]]$postes=(Get-WmiObject -ComputerName SSigcimpr001 -Namespace "root\sms\site_pr1" -Query ("select SMS_R_System.Name from  SMS_R_System WHERE SMS_R_System.Name like '" + $poste_entre + "' AND SMS_R_System.Active = 1")).Name`

By the way, technically these are [WQL queries](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394606%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). The syntax is similar to SQL, but there are subtle differences in the syntax that are more limiting in WQL.

Comment: Thanks a lot for all the information. I edited my question, it's still not working (showing both inactive and active computers?)

Comment: Ah i just saw it, ACTIVE is both to YES on computers but CLIENT ACTIVITY is inactive/active. I just have to find that name of the Client Activity to put in the query.

Comment: Found it, had to get the value right: 

[string[]]$postes=(Get-WmiObject -ComputerName SSigcimpr001 -Namespace "root\sms\site_pr1" -Query ("select SMS_R_System.Name from  SMS_R_System  inner join SMS_G_System_CH_ClientSummary on SMS_G_System_CH_ClientSummary.ResourceId = SMS_R_System.ResourceId where SMS_G_System_CH_ClientSummary.ClientActiveStatus = 1 AND SMS_R_System.Name like '" + $poste_entre + "' ")).Name